# Inject EJB annotation

Tags: java, ejb, inject

When I use annotation @EJB in my code all work fine

```
public class CatalogueDetailsPage extends AbstractBasePage {
    @EJB(lookup = "java:global/mobile.bank.services-1.0.5/api.ejb-1.1/CatalogueFacadeBean!by.softclub.common.api.ICatalogueService")
    private ICatalogueService iCatalogueService;
}
```

But when I want use @Inject & @Produces I have error null pointer

```
public class CatalogueDetailsPage extends AbstractBasePage {
    @Inject
    @EJBBean
    private ICatalogueService iCatalogueService;
}

@Stateless
public class EJBFactory {

    @EJB(lookup = "java:global/mobile.bank.services-1.0.5/api.ejb-
    protected ICatalogueService iCatalogueService;

   @Produces
   @EJBBean
   public ICatalogueService getiCatalogueService() {
        return iCatalogueService;
    }
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface EJBBean {

}

}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: @ManagedBean(name = "catalogueDetailsPage")
@ViewScoped CatalogueDetailsPage